# Как правильно осуществить глобальное использование socket.io в приложении express?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, express

Коротко о структуре того что есть. При запуске приложения

```
  server.listen(port);
  server.on('error', onError);
  server.on('listening', onListening);

  require('socket')(server);
```

Строка `require('socket')(server)` - подключает файл:

```
module.exports = function(server){
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    io.set('origins','*:*');
    //io.set('origins','localhost:*');

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        log.info("Socket is connect");
    });
};
```

Теперь, ближе к делу, в приложении есть контроллеры которые унаследованы от базового:

```
var BaseController = require("core/base/baseController");

class AccountPageController extends BaseController{
  constructor(params){
    super(params);
    //more actions ...
  }

  methodForPage (){
    //more actions ...
  }

}

module.exports = AccountPageController;
```

И, допустим, есть необходимость внутри `methodForPage()` послать сообщение примерно таким образом:

```
socket.emit('msg',{text:'server say:' + new Date()});
```

Но, переменная `socket` доступна только внутри `io.on('connection')`.
**Как ее сделать доступной внутри контроллера? Или как определить ее внутри базового контроллера чтобы она была таким образом доступной во всех контроллерах?**

И, есть еще один момент, например есть необходимость внутри контроллера установить событие socket'a, например так:

```
methodForPage (){

//more actions ...

socket.on('msg', (data) => {
  //do record data to db
  this.dbh.query(/*more actions*/);
});

//more actions ...

}
```

И при этом мы хотим использовать свойства этого контроллера чтобы осуществлять, например, запись данных полученных из сокета в базу данных.

**Можно ли все вышеперечисленное реализовать в таком виде и если да, то что для этого нужно сделать? Правильный ли это подход?**

Comment: Ваша проблема не в socket.io, а в архитектуре. Самое простое, что вам можно посоветовать - замените var io= на global.io= и его будет видно отовсюду. Но учтите, что это совсем не best practice

Comment: спасибо, а best practice в чем тогда заключается? Приведите какие-либо примеры что решат конкретно мою задачу, буду очень раз рассмотреть/изучить

Comment: Тут масса вариантов. Я предпочитаю архитектуру в виде дерева, где есть что-то вроде god object, из которого доступны все модули, который выполняет роль диспетчера между ними и единой точки доступа для всех частей приложения.Обычно он у меня либо лежит в global, либо передается во все конструкторы/модули. Но не факт что это лучшее решение, для каждого конкретного случая нужно отдельно смотреть. Будем надеяться, что вам напишут полноценный ответ на эту тему.

Comment: благодарю вас. А вы можете сказать, чем плохо использование таких вещей через global? И почему многие так опасаются использовать это?

Comment: Ну, это примерно как goto. Гораздо проще выстрелить себе в ногу (в данном случае - перетереть что-то важное из глобальной области), кроме того если всё класть в глобал, есть шанс что сборщик мусора будет собирать меньше.

Comment: God Object тоже антипаттерн. Правильное решение IoC, но оно, почему-то не популярно у javascript программистов. Основная проблема global - изоляция зависимостей (тестирование и прочее).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы столкнулись с характерной для ООП подхода проблемой: *откуда брать зависимости?*

Есть несколько вариантов решения проблемы. Самым очевидным является использование **глобальных переменных**, но этот вариант подходит только для очень маленьких проектов либо проектов, которые не нужно поддерживать. О том, почему вредны глобальные переменные написано уже очень большое количество различных статей. Все проблемы получаются из одного очень простого факта: код становится слишком сильно связанным (tight coupling). Как следствие это выливается в невозможность повторного использования кода, проблемы с модульным тестированием, сложность в отладке приложений и прочее. В средних и крупных проектах все это приводит через некоторое время к такой каше, что становится проще переписать все с нуля.

Классическим решением проблемы, которое редко используют JavaScript разработчики, является подход с [**инверсией управления**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) (Inversion of Control). Одним из вариантов реализации этого подхода является принцип [внедрения зависимостей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) (Dependency Injection), при котором все зависимости "спускаются сверху". Вы, кстати, уже используете его, когда передаете объект `server` модулю отвечающему за инициализацию `socket.io`.

Следуя этому подходу, вы должны сделать следующее:

1. Возвращаете экземпляр `socket.io` из функции, экспортируемой в файле `socket.js`:

   ```
   module.exports = function(server) {
       let io = require('socket.io')(server);
       // ...
       return io;
   }
   ```
2. Объявляете экземпляр `socket.io` **явной** зависимостью базового контролера (или некого агрегатора маршрутов):

   ```
   class BaseController {
       constructor(params) {
           this.io = params.io;
       }
   }

   module.exports = BaseController;
   ```
3. Используете экземпляр `socket.io` в дочерних контроллерах (или реальных маршрутах):

   ```
   let BaseController = require('base_controller');

   class FooBarController extends BaseController {
       constructor(params) {
           super(params);

           this.io.on('msg', this.handleMessage.bind(this));
       }

       handleMessage() {
           // ....
       }
   }

   module.exports = FooBarController;
   ```
4. В основном файле проекта передаете зависимости в явном виде (можно использовать DI контейнер, но это мне кажется несколько избыточным):

   ```
   let initSocket = require('socket'),
       FooBarController = require('foo_bar_controller');

   // Вот здесь вы инициализируете сервер, а я для простоты использую пустой объект
   let server = {};

   // Передаете сервер для инициализации socket.io
   let io = initSocket(server);

   // Передаете экземпляр socket.io для инициализации контролера
   let controller = new FooBarController({io});

   // Запускаете собранное приложение
   server.listen();
   ```

Comment: Благодарю вас, за очень полезный и обширный ответ! Я пока еще не попробовал ваш совет на практике, но взглянув на код, у меня появляется вопрос, это касается п. 4. Здесь вы пишете, что в пусковом  файле проекта, мы подключаем дочерний контроллер и передаем в него экземпляр socket.io для инициализации, но дело в том, что в моем проекте контроллеры всегда инициализируются в роутах: router.get("/fooBar", function(req, res) {
 var controller = new FooBarController(res,req);
 controller.viewPage();
});

Comment: И я не совсем понимаю как это будет работать, и почему необходимо инициализировать дочерние контроллеры в основном файле проекта (их же может быть очень много), и как в них потом попадет req и res? Возможно я неправильно все делаю, и структура проекта неправильно построена, очень хотел бы чтобы вы направили меня на правильный путь!

Comment: @sanu0074, если говорит о множественный контроллерах, то вы вполне можете ввести дополнительный промежуточный уровень, который будет получать `io` при инициализации и уже сам инициализировать контроллеры. Собственно, при инициализации роутера идея та же: вы экспортируете из файла функцию, которая получает `io` и возвращает роутер. Точно так же, как вы передаете `server` функции, возвращающей `io`

Comment: @sanu0074, вообще суть DI сводится к тому, что вы должны создавать зависимости на как можно более высоком уровне и уже потом передавать их туда, где они нужны. Но и в крайности впадать тоже не нужно =)

Comment: т.е.  вы имеете в виду что в конкретном случае, io можно получать где-то на уровне роута, и там уже передавать в дочерний контроллер вместе с req и res, как в примере выше?

Comment: @sanu0074, `io` можно передавать в то место, где генерируется роутер, а потом уже предавать в контролер через конструктор. что касается `req` и `res`, то тут могут быть варианты. я бы скорее использовал методы контролер как обработчики запросов

Comment: Я хотел еще спросить у вас по этому поводу, есть идея, сохранять сокет в сессию при авторизации, т.е. в middleware который отвечает за авторизацию юзера ,будет доступен объект io, и на шаге, когда мы понимаем, авторизованный это юзер или гость - мы делаем нечто подобное:  io.on('connection',(socket) => {  log.info("Socket is connect");  req.session.socket = socket; }); И уже в каком-либо контроллере мы можем работать с сокетом: req.session.socket.on('msg',this.handleMessage.bind(this)); Вы, как человек с хорошим опытом, можете дать комментарий касательно этого подхода? И будет ли это работать?

Comment: @sanu0074, Если честно, я сомневаюсь, что экземпляр сокета можно нормально сериализовать/десериализовать для хранения в произвольном сессионном хранилище. Как следствие, я бы скорее хранил в сессии ID сокет-соединения и при необходимости [вытаскивал](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055989/socket-io-1-0-x-get-socket-by-id) бы экземпляр сокета по ID.

Comment: А вы не могли бы дать совет, как реализовать io.on('connection', (socket) => {//..}); в одном едином месте, чтобы то что содержит в (socket) => использовать повсеместно в контроллерах?

Comment: @sanu0074, А чем вам не нравится подход с сессиями? Вы в одном месте добавляете ID сокета в сессию, а в котролерах, зная ID сокета и имея объект `io` получаете объект сокета. Дальше делаете с ним что хотите

Comment: Так, ведь чтобы получить `ID` сокета, нужно чтобы сначала выполнилось событие `connect`? А в мидлваре который работает с сессией оно может не произойти в некоторых случаях (прим. страница сайта на которой сокет не нужен). Отсюда и актуальность вопроса о том как реализовать коннект сокета в едином месте. Я не совсем понимаю как это реализовать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33406/discussion-between-dmitriy-simushev-and-sanu0074).