# Правильное использование redis и socket.io в express js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, express, redis

Как лучше всего реализовать работу с сокетами и редисом в приложении. Есть ли какие паттерны? Данные модули у меня используются в роутах, моделях и контроллерах. Думал глобально использовать, но понял, что это лиха беда начало. Если не трудно, то можно с примерами.

Comment: А в чем именно заключается проблема? Видели вот этот вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/476867/182771 ?

Comment: проглядел, увидел его, как только отписал вопрос.
Сейчас ознакомлюсь, если возникнут вопросы - задам тут

Comment: _Сейчас ознакомлюсь, если возникнут вопросы - задам тут_ stackoverflow так не работает. Если этот вопрос - дубликат, он должен быть закрыт. А если он отличается и имеет свою конкретику, она должна быть отражена в самом вопросе.

Comment: Дмитрий, а у вас нет случайно, полного примера на гит хабе? Я просто столкнулся с некоторыми проблемами реализации этого DI паттерна. Я использую express.js, а в новой версии, там еще добавили bin/www файл и я не понял, как туда еще прикрутить ваш пример. 2 вопрос: Получается, мне нужно будет в файле проекта, где initSocket, прописывать все контроллеры? А если я использую сокеты и redis библиотеку, то по аналогии делается, т.е. в конструкторе буду писать 2 строку по типу: this.redis = params.redis;?

Comment: Полного, общедоступного примера у меня, увы нет. При реализации DI нужно иметь в виду только один факт: Все зависимости, должны создаваться на как можно более высоком уровне и спускаться вниз по иерархии вложенных объектов. Все остальное -- детали реализации. Применительно к передаче инициализированного redis, то тут все аналогично передаче экземпляра socket.io

Comment: Т.е. самым высоким уровнем у меня является файл bin/www, a не app.js. Значит все зависимости я прописываю там или я что-то не понимаю. Потому что доступ к server задается в www.

Comment: Увы я не знаком со структурой проекта, о котором вы говорите. В тоже время, имеет смысл не слепо использовать самый высокий уровень вообще, а выбрать некий разумный уровень инициализации приложения.

Comment: Извините, еще раз за беспокойство, если говорить о конкретном примере, который вы привели,
как объект io передать в файл роутов? А в самих роутах я уже создаю объект контроллера: let controller = new FooBarController({io});
и потом прописываю сами пути с вызовом метода по такому типу:
router.get('/', controller.homePage);