# Node.js глобальный доступ

Tags: node.js

Есть скрипт, index.js

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var Users = require('./Users');

var connection = mysql.createConnection... //подключение к бд

console.log( Users.getUserInfo(131) );// undefined
```

В файле Users.js

```
module.exports = {
    getUserInfo : function(userId){
        // Необходимо что бы connection - это был object бд.
        console.log(typeof connection)
    }
}
```

Метод Users.getUserInfo(131); Возвращает undefined, оно верно все, но вот вопрос, как реализовать правильно, что бы в файле Users можно было напрямую обращаться к базе?...

Есть мысль, сделать так:

**Users.js**

```
module.exports = {
    db : false,
    getUserInfo : function(userId){
        // Необходимо что бы connection - это был object бд.
        console.log(typeof connection)
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var Users = require('./Users');


var connection = mysql.createConnection... //подключение к бд

Users.db = connection;

console.log( Users.getUserInfo(131) );// **теперь уже object**
```

Но правильно ли так делать?

Comment: Вот в этом вопросе уже поднималась проблема передачи зависимостей в Node.js: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/476867/182771 . Если вкратце, вам стоит передавать объект соединения всем заинтересованным сторонам явно.

Comment: Ну и вместо одного соединения вам стоило бы использовать пул, благо модуль mysql в node.js позволяет делать это из коробки.

Comment: Почитаем про пуллы, обязательно